# What is the sweet spot PC configuration to download and build android AOSP (as of 2022)?

Tags: android-source

What is the sweet spot PC configuration to download and build android AOSP (as of 2022)?
I am new to PC building and don't have much knowledge about PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the complete system requirements and recomendations at https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements

> - A 64-bit environment is required for Android 2.3.x (Gingerbread) and higher versions, including the master branch. You can compile older versions on 32-bit systems.
> - At least 250GB of free disk space to check out the code and an extra 150 GB to build it. If you conduct multiple builds, you need additional space.
> - At least 16 GB of available RAM is required, but Google recommends 64 GB.
>   As of June 2021, Google is using 72-core machines with 64 GB of RAM internally, which take about 40 minutes for a full build (and just a few minutes for incremental builds, depending on exactly which files were modified). By contrast, a 6-core machine with a similar amount of RAM takes 3 hours.

Comment: So is a 32gb ram build fine?

Comment: Yes, for sure. I once used a 16 gb ram PC and a Inter Core i5 processor, it took four hours of building

Comment: So I guess 32gb build with i7000K should take around two hours of build thanks!